# Order of thrown errors?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred, jquery-3

I have a function that upon error (for example "timeout") is supposed to throw an error, which I catch at the end of the promise chain.

```
var createOrder = function (id) {
    Utility.toggleProgressBar();
    return $.ajax({
        url: 'http://' + AppVar.ServerUrlWithPort + '/restapi/CreateOrder',
        data: JSON.stringify({
            'SessionId': AppVar.SessionId,
            'Idrmtreq': id
        }),
    }).then(function (response) {
        if (response.ResultCode === '0') {
            return response;
        } else {
            throw new Error($.i18n('Error-RetrivingDataProblem'));
        }
    }).fail(function (x, t, m) {
        if (t === "timeout") {
            throw new Error($.i18n('Error-Timeout')); //code reaches here, where Chrome debugger says that this error was left Uncaught
            //for the record, I checked whether the translation function could be the problem and it doesn't work even when I do 'throw "timeout";'
        } else {
            throw new Error($.i18n('Error-ConnError'))
        }
    }).catch(function (error) {
        //error == {"readyState":0,"status":0,"statusText":"timeout"}
        ErrorManager.displayError(error);
        return;
    }).always(function () {
        Utility.toggleProgressBar();
    })
}
```

To be specific, I'm experiencing a problem with the timeout. Code reaches to the throw. The throw I threw is actually left Uncaught, but something gets thrown. The Catch catches an error that contains this Object `{"readyState":0,"status":0,"statusText":"timeout"}`.

I don't understand. What's throwing it?

Comment: What jQuery version are you using?

Comment: `.fail` doesn't do what you think it does

Comment: $.ajax is throwing it.

Comment: @Jonasw So, it's throwing it with a delay? As I said, I can breakpoint all the way to the actual throw and throw it, at which point my catch will  catch the ajax error? That's strange.

Comment: it seems that `catch` is fired when the promise is rejected, not when error is thrown. you still got to wrap with `try{ }catch(err){ }` i guess

Comment: @Bergi jQuery 3.1.1

Comment: @Bergi Oh, actually, I think I see the problem. .fail is supposed to be coupled with .done, which I replaced with then somewhere along the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never use `done` or `fail`. They don't chain (and don't catch exceptions).

The `fail()` call returns the original promise, which in your case means that the original error just falls through. You could use [`.catch()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.catch/) instead, but notice that [chaining `.then(…).catch(…)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24662289/1048572) would make it to also handle the *Error-RetrivingDataProblem*. Instead you'll want to use

```
return $.ajax({
    url: 'http://' + AppVar.ServerUrlWithPort + '/restapi/CreateOrder',
    data: JSON.stringify({
        'SessionId': AppVar.SessionId,
        'Idrmtreq': id
    }),
}).then(function (response) {
    if (response.ResultCode === '0') {
        return response;
    } else {
        throw new Error($.i18n('Error-RetrivingDataProblem'));
    }
}, function(x, t, m) { /*
^^^ */
    throw new Error($.i18n(t === "timeout" ? 'Error-Timeout' : 'Error-ConnError'));
}).catch(function (error) {
    ErrorManager.displayError(error);
    return;
})
```

Comment: That works perfectly. Thank you. Wrapping my mind around promises is harder than I expected.